# How to hide a member function when the base class uses generics

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have the following classes, and when I call `CreateQuerySettings` on the BaseScriptConfigurationList, it returns the new `QuerySettings` from `ConfigurationList`, rather than the `HierarchicalQuerySettings` value in `BaseScriptConfigurationList`:

```
public abstract class ConfigurationList<TConfigurationObject, TPropertyEnum>
{
  public QuerySettings<TConfigurationObject, TPropertyEnum> CreateQuerySettings()
  {
    return new QuerySettings<TConfigurationObject, TPropertyEnum>();
  }
}

public class BaseScriptConfigurationList : EditableConfigurationList<BaseScriptConfiguration, BaseScriptConfiguration.Property>
{
  public BaseScriptConfigurationList(ConfigurationManager configurationManager)
    : base(configurationManager, InternalAdminObjectType.BaseScript)
  {
     _BaseScriptPageListWatcher = new ConfigurationList<BaseScriptPageConfiguration, BaseScriptPageConfiguration.Property>.
     ConfigurationWatcher(null);

      _ConfigurationWatcher.ChildWatchers.Add(_BaseScriptPageListWatcher);

  }

  public new QuerySettings<BaseScriptConfiguration, BaseScriptConfiguration.Property> CreateQuerySettings()
  {
    return new HierarchicalQuerySettings<BaseScriptConfiguration, BaseScriptConfiguration.Property, BaseScriptQueryChildrenSettings>();
  }
}
```

Edit: I make the call from another class where `TConfigurationObjectList` is `BaseScriptConfigurationList`. I've added the constructor to the code above so you can see what it's doing. Please note that EditableConfigurationList inherits from ConfigurationList.

```
TConfigurationObjectList cl = (TConfigurationObjectList)typeof(TConfigurationObjectList).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(ConfigurationManager) }).Invoke(new object[] { Manager.ConfigurationManager });
var querySettings = cl.CreateQuerySettings();
```

When I make this call, it goes into the ConfigurationList.CreateQuerySettings method.

How can I hide the `CreateQuerySettings` method, so that when I call it from the `BaseScriptConfigurationList` class, I get a `HierarchicalQuerySettings` object?

Comment: Please provide the code that you used to call create BaseScriptConfigurationList object to know exactly the situation you are encountered.

Comment: Indeed, we're not seeing the whole picture here -- where's the definition of EditableConfigurationList? Also, the fact that the "Base" class is a subclass is particularly confusing.

Comment: I have added the calling code to help explain what's happening.

Comment: @Rachel Martin, updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `BaseScriptConfigurationList.CreateQuerySettings()`
you're return type is `QuerySettings<T,T>` so you will always get that type as a return value, but you are returning a `HierarchicalQuerySettings`. You can one, change the return type of `CreateQuerySettings()` to `HierarchicalQuerySettings` or two, cast the object to its child type "`HierarchicalQuerySettings`". If you really want to hide it, you can do this:

```
public class newclass : BaseScriptConfigurationList
{
    public new HierarchicalQuerySettings<BaseScriptConfiguration, BaseScriptConfiguration.Property> CreateQuerySettings()
    {
        return (HierarchicalQuerySettings<BaseScriptConfiguration, BaseScriptConfiguration.Property>)base.CreateQuerySettings();
    }
}
```

But that doesn't really seem efficient and i advise against it. Like i said, i maybe missing some other requirement, but based on the info that you gave..

---

Basically, what I'm seeing (and making assumptions) that `TConfigurationObjectList` Inhertis from `ConfigurationList` somewhere along the lines, so on and so forth, all the way up to `EditableConfigurationList`. since you are dynamically creating an instance of the class TConfigurationObjectList, and calling the method from that point, you will be calling the base `ConfigurationList` member `CreateQuerySettings`. You do not have access to the new CreateQuerySettings. If you are creating the class `BaseScriptConfigurationList` instance at this point, cast the object `((BaseScriptConfigurationList)cl).CreateQuerySettings()`. That being said. if you do not know what you have at runtime:

```
var obj = typeof(TConfigurationObjectList).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(ConfigurationManager) }).Invoke(new object[] { Manager.ConfigurationManager });
var cl = (obj  as BaseScriptConfigurationList) ?? (TConfigurationObjectList)obj;
// or do something else
var querySettings = cl.CreateQuerySettings();
```

---

Note i am assuming your architecture is roughly set up like this:

```
public abstract class ConfigurationList<TConfigurationObject, TPropertyEnum>
{
    public QuerySettings<TConfigurationObject, TPropertyEnum> CreateQuerySettings()
    {
        return new QuerySettings<TConfigurationObject, TPropertyEnum>();
    }
}

public class TConfigurationObjectList : ConfigurationList<BaseScriptConfiguration, BaseScriptConfiguration.Property>
{

}

public class EditableConfigurationList<T, T1> : TConfigurationObjectList
{
    protected EditableConfigurationList(ConfigurationManager configurationManager, object baseScript)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class BaseScriptConfigurationList : EditableConfigurationList<BaseScriptConfiguration, BaseScriptConfiguration.Property>
{
    public BaseScriptConfigurationList(ConfigurationManager configurationManager)
        : base(configurationManager, InternalAdminObjectType.BaseScript)
    {

    }

    public new QuerySettings<BaseScriptConfiguration, BaseScriptConfiguration.Property> CreateQuerySettings()
    {
        return new HierarchicalQuerySettings<BaseScriptConfiguration, BaseScriptConfiguration.Property, BaseScriptQueryChildrenSettings>();
    }
}

public class QuerySettings<T, T1>
{
}

public class HierarchicalQuerySettings<T, T1, T2> : QuerySettings<BaseScriptConfiguration, BaseScriptConfiguration.Property>
{
}

public class BaseScriptQueryChildrenSettings
{
}

public class BaseScriptPageConfiguration
{
    public class Property
    {
    }
}

public class InternalAdminObjectType
{
    public static object BaseScript { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigurationManager
{
}

public class BaseScriptConfiguration
{
    public class Property
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your clarifications help me understand where we're disconnecting. `TConfigurationObjectList` is a generic type on the calling method. It looks like this: `RetrieveReferencedObjects<TConfigurationObject, TConfigurationObjectList, TPropertyEnum>(TPropertyEnum idProperty, IEnumerable<ConfigurationId> ids)`

Therefore, when I try to do `var cl = (obj  as BaseScriptConfigurationList) ?? (TConfigurationObjectList)obj;`, it fails to compile.

In the case I'm outlining above, `TConfigurationObjectList` is `BaseScriptConfigurationList`.

Comment: Also, roughly speaking,
`public abstract class EditableConfigurationList<TConfigurationObject, TPropertyEnum> : ConfigurationList<TConfigurationObject, TPropertyEnum>`

Comment: In the case defined,  you will have to cast it to the BaseConfigurationList to access the member you want. Or if it is always that type, you can cast the QuerySettings. And if it always that type just cast it on the constuctor call.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and mark this as the answer. I was able to create a `BaseScriptConfigurationList` to call `CreateQuerySettings` from. Then, I can set querySettings to the value I get. I suspect the problem is actually in the way the constructor is being called, but I'm unable to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The `new` modifier can be beasty. Note that you are **hiding** and not **overriding** in your example. You are not showing that part of the code, but I assume you have this situation:

```
class Base
{
   public static void BaseMethod() { Console.WriteLine("BASE!"); }
}

class Derived : Base
{
   // Hides Base.BaseMethod()
   new public static void BaseMethod() { Console.WriteLine("DERIVED!"); }   
}

Base a = new Base();
a.BaseMethod(); // -> "BASE!"

Base b = new Derived();
b.BaseMethod(); // -> "BASE!"

Derived b = new Derived();
b.BaseMethod(); // -> "DERIVED!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a base interface for the `ConfigurationList` class (say `IConfigurationList`) and use this interface as the data type for the variable `cl` instead of `TConfigurationList`.